# How to add Font Awesome to Blazor client (Razor component) app?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor, font-awesome, blazor-webassembly

I created a Blazor WebAssembly hosted template in .NET Core 3.1. Then right clicked on *project.Client/wwwroot/css* folder and clicked on <kbd>Add client side library</kbd>. Then selected the Font Awesome library and installed it. I added the below line to *index.html* `<head>`.

```
 <link href="css/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I have *libman.json* of:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultProvider": "cdnjs",
  "libraries": [
    {
      "library": "font-awesome@5.11.2",
      "destination": "wwwroot/css/font-awesome/"
    }
  ]
}
```

I added just the below line to the default Blazor template page *Counter.razor* (Razor component). The IntelliSense finds the font:

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<span class="fa fa-save"></span>

@code {}
```

but I only see a square:

[image]

Comment: I've added this script element copied from w3schools to the _Host.cshtml file

     `<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>`

And it works. I'm not familiar with these toys, but I guess you need to get a code like **a076d05399** to enable it. I'm using here the code from a sample by w3schools. How it should be done when you use the files from wwwroot is not clear to me.

Comment: @Isaac I added your code to index.html file and worked. But as you said it is not using wwwroot content. This script pointed me to this interesting way of employing fontawesome https://blog.fontawesome.com/introducing-font-awesome-kits/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You also need to include the JavaScript.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/fontawesome.min.css" />
<script src="css/font-awesome/js/all.min.js"></script>
```

You can put the `<script>` tag below the other one at the bottom of the file but I doubt that you'll notice any speed difference.

From a now deleted comment:

> The JS is just one option (the preferred option), but CSS only is still an option as well. Also, you don't use both. It's either CSS or JS

In Blazor I could only get the JS version to work. CSS only didn't work (the file was 200-OK).

Comment: The `~/` is added by intellisense. It certainly isn't needed but i don't think it hurts either.

Comment: It didn't worked with ~/ for me. VS2019 16.4 Net Core 3.1, template from running command dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.1.0-preview4.19579.2

Comment: I missed the client-side tag. The ~/ works on server-side but it is altogether better to leave them out. Intellisense should be updated too.

Comment: The highlighted text is correct. I removed the css line, and only left the script and worked as fast as light speed.

Comment: I'm using Blazor and it only works if the js file is present.

Comment: CSS only works fine in Blazor 3. No need for JS.

Answer (score 20):

The **fa** prefix has been deprecated in version 5. The new default is the **fas** solid style and the fab style for brands. [ref](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use)

add to _hosts.cshtml (for server side)

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
```

Use fas as below:

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<span class="fas fa-save"></span>  <!--fas not fa-->

@code {}
```

This is tested in blazor Net5

Comment: This also worked in Blazor .NET 6.

Comment: I can see some icons like `fa-save` or `fa-user` but not `fa-code-pull-request` .. does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 14):

You can use libman (or copy the files manually from the zip available at Fontawesome website). Then install/copy only all.min.css and the whole contents of webfonts folder into wwwroot/css/font-awesome subfolder. Like this:

[image]

Then put this into Pages/_Host.cshtml (for Blazor Server) or wwwroot/index.html (Blazor Web Assembly) into the head section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/all.min.css" />
```

Or, as an alternative, add this at the beginning of site.css:

```
@import url('font-awesome/css/all.min.css');
```

No need for JS. It works.

Comment: I've found this to be the cleanest solution. Worked like a charm in my Blazor Web Assembly app.

Comment: I have a simple button that references FA like `<button class="fas fa-angle-double-up">Up</button>` and I just get an pulsing small question mark. For some reason Blazor decided it couldn't find something. I have the exact link as above.

Comment: i HAD TO use the @import in the site.css to make it work

Answer (score 2):

You have to actually reference the stylesheet in your HTML page. This is usually done in the layout (`_Layout.csthml`). You need to add something like the following in your `<head>`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Comment: I couldn't find _Layout.cshtml in blazor client app project folder. The closest I found was MainLayout.razor. I added to it within a  <head> and without, neither worked.

Comment: In Blazor you have _Host.cshtml. Don't put a `<head>` in _MainLayout. _Layout is used in MVC projects.

Comment: I am working with Blazor client app hosted (wasm). I couldn't find _Host.cshtml.

Comment: wasm is index.html on wwwroot

Comment: If you see square brackets, switch font-awesome.min.css to all.min.css

Answer (score 0):

FontAwesome have multiple framework supported (Vue, React, Angular, WordPress, LESS, SCSS). But I don't know why they are not providing it for Blazor.

So that, I have created "Brushtail.FontAweomse.Blazor" nuget package.

Instructions https://www.nuget.org/packages/Brushtail.FontAwesome.Blazor/