# Errors in adding fontawesome to a Blazor component

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I think I have followed the steps for a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197533/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-blazor-client-razor-component-app) about this question. But I get no error but I get an alternating question mark and exclamation point on the display.
[image: question/exclamation]
There are no errors in the Chrome debugger console. If I hover over these alternating "buttons" I don't get any tooltip or additional information. So it seems that the class has been recognized and the button loaded but there is some kind of error that I cannot determine.
Here is what I have so far

1. Downloaded and the zip of the FA components
   [image: fontawesome components]
2. Add link to index.html under wwwroot (this is a client side Blazor
   application)
3. Referenced the classes in my component

> ```
> <button class="fas fa-angle-double-up">Up</button>
> <button class="fas fa-angle-double-down">Down</button>
> ```

But this doesn't seem to work. Ideas?
I have tried including the .js from Fontawesome but still no luck

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>BreakpointManagement.App</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="BreakpointManagement.App.Client.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/all.min.css" />
    <script src="css/font-awesome/js/all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/BlazorTable/BlazorTable.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you include the `.js` file as well in your `index.html`? Could you post the contents of that file?

Comment: I did not the post I referred to indicated that I didn't need it. I included it just in case but still not luck. i cannot include the full `index.html` but here is the applicable lines
`
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome/css/all.min.css" />
    <script src="css/font-awesome/js/all.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: I installed Font Awesome for Blazor WASM recently.  I have many more folders and files compared to what is in your picture.  For example, I have a folder labeled SVG.  And I can see that the element (in my case an i element) is transformed into an svg element.  I would suggest take a look at the Elements section in Chrome Browser for clues.  Also I am wondering if you got the complete FontAwesome package since you are missing a lot of the folders that came in the downloadable package.

Comment: Perhaps you can also share which version you installed.  I downloaded 5.15.2 free for web which is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I added all paths, as @JasonD mentioned

[image]

added this line at component file

[image]

and added these lines at index.html

[image]

and voi-la

[image]